# Eclipse INDIGO freeze everytime when I run python program

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, freeze

My Eclipse is downloaded some days ago from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and the type is **Eclipse Classic 3.7.1**.

I installed pydev in Eclipse and configuration python in **Windows** -> **Performance** -> **Pydev** -> **Interpreter - Python**.

After everything finished, I write a hello world program, but when I try to run (**Run** -> **Run as** -> **Python Run**) it, the Eclipse would freeze in everytime.

Has anyone met this strange questions?

my configurations:

**Eclipse**: 3.7.1; **Pydev**: 2.3.0, Install method: go to **Help** -> **Install New Software**, and added the pydev updated address: http://pydev.org/updates, and install

**Python**: 2.6.2; **Java**: 1.7.0

Comment: You mean freeze and you have to restart or freeze and you just have to wait some time for it to end launching? When that happens, do you have something in your error log? (http://pydev.org/faq.html#how_do_i_report_a_bug has details on how to get it).

Comment: I have report that bugs, bug ID is 3472857. thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer, that's all because ANSICON, I was install the ANSICON http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon/ for BDD. The purpose of ANSICON is to make command line colorful(that's really beautiful!), but, it seem change something and make Eclipse freeze. Well, if wants Eclipse works, just uninstall the ANSICON.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do my best to help out.

I remember having a similar problem with an earlier version of eclipse. What I did was I removed Eclipse Classic and replaced it with Eclipse for Java Development. Next, I used the pydev which comes with Aptana Studio (and not the independent pydev.org) and my problem (freezing upon executing the interpreter) ceased to exist. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I have downloaded and had a try for Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, but it still cannot work, Eclipse still freezed. I'm going crazy...and what's 'pydev which comes with Aptana Studio' you mean?

Comment: Well, finally, I got the answer, that's all because **ANSICON**, I was install the ANSICON (http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon/) for BDD. The purpose of ANSICON is to make command line colorful(that's really beautiful!), but, it seem change something and make Eclipse freeze. Well, if wants Eclipse works, just uninstall the ANSICON.